# Missing keyword Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have this SQL query and I am getting "MISSING KEYWORD" error.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DUECD = 'PRI' THEN DUEAMT ELSE '0') AS LATESTPRIN, SUM(CASE WHEN DUECD != 'PRI' THEN DUEAMT ELSE '0') AS LATESTINT FROM LLDUEDET WHERE STARTDT = TO_DATE('2020-01-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

What is my mistake? I have been trying to debug this.

Comment: @T.S. sorry, I forgot to delete that the value of TO_DATE is '2020-01-20'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an END inside the parenthesis should be enough:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN DUECD = 'PRI' THEN DUEAMT ELSE '0' END) AS LATESTPRIN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DUECD != 'PRI' THEN DUEAMT ELSE '0' END) AS LATESTINT
FROM
  LLDUEDET
WHERE
  STARTDT = TO_DATE('". $LatestDate ."', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about your codeblock below

`TO_DATE(**’”.$LatestDate.”’**`

but maybe you got something gong on that I’m unaware of.

What I am sure about is that your case statements need an end. See below.

```
SELECT 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DUECD = 'PRI' 
        THEN DUEAMT 
        ELSE '0' 
    END) 
AS LATESTPRIN, 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN DUECD != 'PRI' 
        THEN DUEAMT 
        ELSE '0'
    END) 
AS LATESTINT FROM LLDUEDET 

WHERE STARTDT = TO_DATE('". $LatestDate ."', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: That is for my PHP code I forgot to edit that sorry